# How was I able to mark a question as duplicate on my own?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Could someone tell me how I was able to mark [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696785/display-12-hour-or-24-hour-format-according-to-the-user-location-or-to-the-devic) as a duplicate on my own, without the need for a usual 5-vote system.

Fully expecting the irony that will follow from marking *this* question as duplicate...

Comment: You have a gold badge in the [ios] tag. This gives you the power to close questions with that tag as duplicates.

Comment: Hmmm. I have had that gold badge for some time, but I think this is the first time that's happened.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's a new super power you've been granted.

Comment: When and why was it granted?

Comment: Reference Link: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges/231505#231505)...

Comment: @War10ck I agree with that answer and will have to be more careful than usual with my new found powers (the acquisition of which are still a mystery to me).